# SQL command not properly ended oracle 10g function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I can't run this function. It gives the error:

```
ERROR at line 9: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login(
     name in varchar2,
     pass in varchar2 )
     RETURN NUMBER
    IS 
    v_type NUMBER;
    BEGIN 
    v_type:=-1;
    Select loginfo.type from loginfo into v_type
    where loginfo.username=name and loginfo.password=pass;
    RETURN v_type;
END;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've highlighted your code with the `{}` button to make it readable.

Comment: In addition to @a_horse_with_no_name's comment, if this isn't the answer you'll need to post the DDL of `loginfo`; and please add some error handling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order of

```
Select loginfo.type from loginfo into v_type
```

to

```
Select loginfo.type into v_type from loginfo
```

Comment: @AwladLiton your welcome, please check the green mark and +1 my answer if it helps..